# How to add a <h2> element to a panel?

Tags: gwt

How can I add a HTML  Element to a GWT Panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it this way

```
HTML html = new HTML("<h2>Headline</h2>");

yourpannel.add(html);
```

OR

```
RootPanel.get().add(html);
```

(Supposing your GWT Panel is a HTMLpanel....)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a look at [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html).